Pete's Pike - 7x7 puzzles - Part 1
These puzzles that I have created are inspired by the Thinkfun game Pete's Pike.
We have only red and blue tokens. The aim is to get the red token to the center of the board.

Tokens may only move vertically or horizontally.
Each move, tokens may only move toward another token in the same row or column but they may only stop directly in front of the token they are moving towards.
Tokens may not jump over other token. They must stop directly in front of the first token they encounter in that row or column.

(Note that the grey circle refers to the center of the board, not a token).
Example gameplay

Find a solution to the puzzles below to get the red token to the center of the board. Bonus points if you find the shortest number of steps to reach each solution!
Puzzle 1

Puzzle 2

Puzzle 3


Can the tokens be moved to the boundary? Or can they be moved only to other tokens? Also should "the red counter to the token of the board" be "the red token to the center of the board"?

@Pranay Only to other tokens. They cannot move to the boundary

@Pranay Yes it should say center. I have edited now. Thanks

I would recommend splitting this up into 3 separate puzzles.

Does the red token need to end on the center or simply pass through it?

@LCIII It needs to end in the center, like in the example gameplay
